# How can I load controller data into javascript array?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I am newbie,

I am developing an election app via MVC3(Due to some restrictions). I did everything. It works fine. However, I need some charts to visualize my app.

Found something, working fine with 'static numbers'. I want to load my own data which comes from database. I am not good at Javascript. Here is where I have troubles.

```
var barChartData = {
               labels: ["App1", "App2", "App3", "App3", "App4", "App5", "Soru6"],
               datasets: [
                                   {
                                       fillColor: "rgba(233, 78, 2, 0.9)",
                                       strokeColor: "rgba(233, 78, 2, 0.9)",
                                       highlightFill: "#e94e02",
                                       highlightStroke: "#e94e02",
                                       data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                                   },
                                   {
                                       fillColor: "rgba(79, 82, 186, 0.9)",
                                       strokeColor: "rgba(79, 82, 186, 0.9)",
                                       highlightFill: "#4F52BA",
                                       highlightStroke: "#4F52BA",
                                       data: [40, 70, 55, 20, 45, 70, 60]
                                   }
                               ]

           };
```

First, I want to load some labels into Labels array from db . (Table: User, Column Apps)
Then, I want to load some data into data array. (Table UserQuestion, Column QuestionAnswerRate)

I am able to get both of these data via Model or ViewBag. However can't load into array.

How can I do this?

public ActionResult Index()
        {

```
        ViewBag.Mevzuatlar = _mevzuat.SelectAll(); //First Chart



        return View(_user.Find(f => f.Rol == true && f.KatildiMi == true)); //Second Chart
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

using `@Html.Raw` You can do this way in your scripts.

```
var chartOneData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
var chartTwoData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Data));
```

Comment: My Controller code is
ViewBag.Data = _data.SelectAll();
returnView(_question.SelectAll());

Comment: so you want to show the ViewBag.data into the javascript array or the Model?

Comment: Both. I have 2 different chart in a view. One of them should have the data of the model the other should have the data of the ViewBag(Or better carrier). Thank you

Comment: Just replace the `Model` with your `Viewbag.Data` in the above code and it must work fine

Comment: Thanks. How can I foreach insied it? Should I change my controller?

Comment: why do you want to foreach this?? You can assign it to the chart right?

Comment: labels: ["item1.Name", "item2.Name", "item3.Name", "item4.Name", "İtem5.Name", "item6.Name", "item7.Name"],
               datasets: [
                                   {
                                       fillColor: "rgba(233, 78, 2, 0.9)",
                                       strokeColor: "rgba(233, 78, 2, 0.9)",
                                       highlightFill: "#e94e02",
                                       highlightStroke: "#e94e02",
                                       data: [item1.Data1, item1.Data2, item1.Data3],
                                   },

Comment: you need to chage your controller to pass in `List<string>`

Comment: Thank you! I will try and write again the result.

Comment: But I have object inside objects. So I need foreach inside foreach?

Comment: You need to come up with a logic to build the data as per your requirement. Return list<string> if your chart requires array of data, else return List<yourObject> if your chart requires array of objets